# Vim split function arguments

Tags: vim

I found that I often do refactor:

```
def function(param1, param2, (...), paramK):
```

to

```
def function(
    param1,
    param2,
    (...),
    paramK,       
):
```

And tried to write mapping for it.
I started with

```
command! Split normal! qqqf(a<cr><esc>qqf s<cr><esc>@qq@qf)i<cr><esc>

qqq - reset content of macro q.

f(a<cr><esc> - find bracket, make newline and return to normal mode.

qq - start to record macro q.

f s<cr><esc> - change space to newline.

@q - run macro recursively.

q@q - end recording and run.

f)i<cr><esc> - add last newline before closing bracket.
```

My idea was, that macro will fail when it won't find space, but something is wrong with that. It raised some questions.

1) How can I check if some motion succeed? e.g. How to check if there is a space in current line?

2) Is there better idea to achieve what I want? Maybe some plugin or clear function?

3) What is wrong with my idea? When I run this combination from hand it works, but while calling :Split it doesn't.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733909/easily-reformatting-function-arguments-onto-multiple-lines-in-vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding why it doesn't work quite like it does when you type it manually:

When you type `normal! <esc>`, Vim parses this as "type the letters `<`, `e`, `s`, `c`, `>`". You might be able to insert a literal escape key there by typing `<c-v><esc>`, but that can look a bit weird in the configuration. Instead, a better way is to use the `:exe` command ([`:help :exe`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3aexe)):

```
exe "normal! \<esc>"
```

The `\<esc>` gets interpolated *by the string* to be a literal escape key. So, the `exe "normal! ..."` gets translated to an invocation to `normal!` with the keys you're looking for. You also need to escape `<cr>` the same way. I'd also use `\<space>` instead of , I'm not entirely sure if a normal space is going to work here. After that, hopefully, you should get the same results as when you type it manually.

---

As for the actual problem you're trying to solve, I do have a plugin for that: [splitjoin](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim). By default, it splits your example like this:

```
def function(param1,
        param2,
        (...),
        paramK):
    pass
```

But there's a [setting](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim/blob/26e9e9b0d34de581a15e9ed4ff82562bb0e8c2e8/doc/splitjoin.txt#L1363-L1388) you can change to adjust it to your liking. Alternatively, from Jordan Running's link, it seems you could also use the [argwrap](https://github.com/FooSoft/vim-argwrap/) plugin, which might be more reliable for argument-splitting in particular (splitjoin handles a wider variety of cases, but maybe doesn't do as good with arguments? Not sure.)

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. I don't understand the question. You can search for spaces with `f` or with the `/` syntax. Why do you want to do this?
2. Yes. See below.
3. The `vimrc` syntax is super different from normal vim syntax. I don't know why and I don't fully understand it.

Code:

```
nnoremap <C-r> :s/, */,\r    /g<cr>:s/)/\r)<cr>:nohl<cr>
```

remaps ctrl+r to search for a comma followed by 0 or more spaces and replace that with a comma, newline, and tab. then searches for `)` and replaces that with newline and ). then undoes the highlighting it just did.

To enter a literal tab instead of 4 spaces, you'll have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> in place of the 4 spaces you see in the command

Comment: 1) I wanted to use it in vim function.

2) Your solution doesn't work for nested functions.

3) But should't normal! keyword just run normal mode mappings?